# Selecting multiple columns from a subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, subquery

I've searched a lot, but still no chance on having a subquery to return multiple columns all at once. The following code works, but it sucks:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Column1 FROM dbo.fnGetItemPath(ib.Id)) AS Col1,
    (SELECT Column2 FROM dbo.fnGetItemPath(ib.Id)) AS Col2,
    (SELECT Column3 FROM dbo.fnGetItemPath(ib.Id)) AS Col3
FROM ItemBase ib
```

I actually have got no idea how to pass ib.Id to the function and get the entire Column1, Column2, Column3 columns without calling the fnGetItemPath function 3 times.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code for the function? If it's a table valued function then it should work,

Comment: Yes, it's a table-valued function. But the above SQL code really isn't efficient, since it has to run the function 3 different times separately, which is useless. I need a mechanism to run the function once to get the three columns all at once. Any idea?

Comment: If its a table valued function then you don't have to do it as above, you can just SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGetItemPath(ib.Id))

Comment: Also it looks like it isn't running the code 3 times but rather 3 times for each ID. Can you not rather write the fnGetItemPath() to output the full solution? i.e. get rid of the WHERE id = part of the function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move ti to "FROM" part and use [outer apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) (or cross apply).

check syntax yourself, but it should look something like this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM ItemBase ib
Outer Apply dbo.fnGetItemPath(ib.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

doesn't this work?

```
select 
     (select column1, column2, column3 from dbo.fnGetItemPath(ib.Id)) 
from ItemBase ib
```

or do you need something else?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. It fails since "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."